# Where can I find an "official" list of English graphemes?

Tags: phonemes

Do you know of a list provided by some academic institution? I did find some lists, but I am unable to judge the quality and/or completeness of these:

- [This pdf](http://www.dyslexia-reading-well.com/support-files/the-44-phonemes-of-english.pdf), referenced [here](http://www.dyslexia-reading-well.com/44-phonemes-in-english.html).
- and [this pdf](http://www.phonicsinternational.com/unit1_pdfs/DH%20Alph%20Code%20overview%20with%20teaching%20points%20-%20A4x7.pdf), referenced [here](http://www.mumsnet.com/Talk/primary/1307203-Complete-list-of-phonemes-graphemes-and-questions-please).

Background: I am trying to program a random name generator for project working titles, using the [approach outlined here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/91887/63949), by extracting graphemes from these [downloadable free corpus samples](https://www.english-corpora.org/full-text/formats.asp) and feeding it to some kind of [markov chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain).

UPDATE:

I used the Wikipedia list as suggested by @tchrist and the free COCA sample corpus referenced above. The approach worked quite well for my purposes. Here is a small random set of generated words for anyone interested:

```
Wanstasy, Indricis, Voformer, Colutove, Ingerstr, Tottione, Lspheres,
Umandsam, Extivelo, Pironoba, Zofiropr, Bingernt, Kitleron, Viewinef,
Juntialt, Enabbyth, Uplpofor, Everopeo, Heventri, Ntozzler, Buncener, 
Granalse, Nocosacc, Randeren, Randantu, Caredyou, Ftedowla, Ncesnarr, 
Ulilkien, Factitur, Grontoft, Noughtoo, Lackeded, Zofricsp, Viewedon, 
Tuartand, Dossions, Kifreaps, Xicatage, Evertsom, Emorever, Manksgis, 
Ponkiold, Nsualina, Atofficl, Mallitsi, Spmethir, Dayspeed, Anditout, 
Xatofrse, Izamedoo, Bupleati, Plitteni, Failitha, Hinglood, Dcoveyou,
```

Comment: "Official" makes no sense. Furthermore, whether something is a digraph/trigraph etc. depends. OA is such in *coat* but not *coalesce*; TH is such in *bathhouse* but not in *boathouse*. There is no end of these.

Comment: @tchrist Eventually I will work with whatever I can find, including the lists provided in the question...

Comment: I wonder whether the various spellings for each given phoneme listed in [Wikipedia’s section on “Sound to Spelling Correspondences” in their article on **English Orthography**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_orthography#Sound_to_spelling_correspondences) might be of any use to you for sussing out possible graphemes in English.

Comment: Ok, I’ve looked at both your PDF sources: the Wikipedia section is better than either of those. Your task is harder than you may realize.

Comment: Thanks for that - I wasn't aware of that wikipedia list, you might want to turn that into an answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a resource request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the various spellings for each given phoneme listed in [Wikipedia’s section on “Sound to Spelling Correspondences” in their article on English Orthography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_orthography#Sound_to_spelling_correspondences), this may help.

I’ve looked at both your PDF sources: the Wikipedia section is better than either of those. Your task is harder than you may realize.

Comment: I ended up using this Wikipedia list. It worked quite well for my purposes. Thanks again.

Comment: @Zalumon Your results are quite good, and I bet you could make them even better. Some of the initial and final sequences don't work. I'm thinking if you include a special empty element to represent the beginning and end of the word for feeding to your markov chains, that that issue might go away.

Comment: Yes, I see your point. Currently I treat all graphemes identically. I should definitely have separate probabilities for word boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

I get what you mean because there are officially over 44 that include the American and British, but I don't know where to find it, and I'm looking for it as well. :/ But check page R45 of the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary, you'll find it there with an example each. If you don't want to use a dictionary, then I'm sorry.